# Insert Rails without sending null values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, rails-activerecord

I have a table in SQL Server set up with a default value for a `uniqueidentifier not null`.

I do not want ActiveRecord to send the null value to the database, but it is, causing a 'Cannot insert null value into not null column' error.

How do I save an ActiveRecord without sending columns that have defaults? I don't really want to:

1. Making the columns nullable.
2. Using Rails to generate the GUID and sending it to the database
3. Writing the query manually.

I *could* do either 2 or 3 this seems like something that *has* to be doable in plain ActiveRecord/RoR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I think this is an issue with Rails with Sql Server as using Rails with MySql handles defaults (and this situation) correctly.  There may be other options, but probably the quickest is to add a before_create callback to your ActiveRecord class and set the guid there.